# How to create update trigger after new record is inserted?

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I have create table in `mysql` .Table name is `sales` which contain following columns 
`saleID int NOT NULL Primary Key,
   productID int NOT NULL,
   unitPrice decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
   quantity int NOT NULL,
   total decimal(6,2)`
Now i want `update trigger` after a new record is inserted which find total price for this sale.

I am trying to write update trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_sales_insert  
before INSERT ON sales
FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN

END#
$$
DELIMITER
```

I am beginner ,please help.Thank you

Comment: In a before insert trigger you can amend NEW. values. But I'm not clear from your code or question if you have acquired the unitprice before the trigger. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for response,but i am beginner,i have no idea about `NEW`.Total unit price for this sale.

Comment: No offence intended but that's why you should read the manual lots of examples in there. And you didn't answer my question about having acquired the unitprice before the trigger is invoked.

Comment: You shouldn't have to store totals in a SQL table, as it is basically against the normalization "rules", You should ideally calculate totals on the fly with a query or in a view.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Not sure I agree it's easier to do that than plough through history tables to find the price applicable at the time the sale happened.(assuming product price can change).

Comment: true @P.Salmon a product price history is a other thing then doing a total sale calucation.. But the topicstarters question isn't about product price history but it seams to be about a pure total price calculation for a sale record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
select productid ,standardcost from awproduct where productid = 707;
+-----------+--------------+
| productid | standardcost |
+-----------+--------------+
|       707 |         3.00 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

and assuming you have not acquired the unitprice before the trigger is invoked

```
drop table if exists t;
drop trigger if exists t;
create table t
(id int, productid int, unitprice int, quantity int, totalprice int);

delimiter $$
create trigger  t
before insert on  t
for each row begin
    set new.unitprice = (select standardcost from awproduct where productid = new.productid);
    set new.totalprice = new.quantity * new.unitprice;

end $$
delimiter ;

insert into t (id,productid,quantity) values
(1,707,10);

select * from t;

+------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| id   | productid | unitprice | quantity | totalprice |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+
|    1 |       707 |         3 |       10 |         30 |
+------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot improve on the documentation in the manual so I ain't going to try. By the way if you want a solution that is closer to your requirement it's better to include sample data as text in the question.

Comment: after applying this trigger,i am trying to insert in table but this error `18:01:19 INSERT INTO sales (saleID,productID,unitPrice,quantity) VALUES (2,23,32.33,2) Error Code: 1048. Column 'unitPrice' cannot be null 0.000 sec` before triggers working fine,insertion successfull